# ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" jdbc postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc

I am running into this error running the following statement on the following table. It looks like I am not using the placeholder syntax correctly but it's not immediately obvious what's wrong. I am using the latest version of the postgres jdbc plugin. Any ideas?

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
  Position: 292

create table if not exists feeds
(
    feed_id          serial primary key,
    title       varchar(50) not null,
    description text,
    docs        text,
    feedType    varchar(50),
    link        varchar(100),
    author      varchar(50),
    authors      varchar(50)[],
    contributors      varchar(50)[],
    copyright      varchar(50),
    categories  varchar(100),
    language    varchar(50),
    uri         varchar(200),
    web_master   varchar(50),
    icon        bytea,
    image       bytea,
    time_stamp   timestamp with time zone not null default current_timestamp
);

insert into feeds("Bitcoin Magazine: Bitcoin News, Articles, Charts, and Guides", "Bitcoin Magazine provides news, analysis, information, commentary and price data about Bitcoin through our website, podcasts, research, and events.", "null", "rss_2.0", "https://bitcoinmagazine.com", "null", ?, ?, "null", "[]", "en", "null", "null", ?, ?)
        returning feed_id;
```

Comment: Why the "?" in insert are you inserting via some variable and `it should be insert into fields values`

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. ? is a placeholder to insert datatypes `<Array>[]>, and `bytea` that I insert in other code not shown here. This insert statement here is dump of the prepared sql statement from the debug console.

Comment: You need to spend some time here [Insert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html), it is insert into feeds(col1, col2, ...) values(val1, val2, ...)

Comment: The error should be something like `column "Bitcoin Magazine: Bitcoin News, Articles, Charts, and Guides" not found`.  The part right after the table name defines the target columns. The actual values are provided in the `values` clause. And string literals are written with single quotes in SQL, not double quotes. So you should use something like `insert into feeds (title, description, ...) values ('Bitcoin Magazine: Bitcoin News, Articles, Charts, and Guides', ...)` For details see [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)